# Blogger Template: how to change the color of the border css

Tags: html, css, border, blogger

I'm trying to change the borders in the style sheet of the template on [my blog](http://mlai-lirik.blogspot.com/), but I've never done anything with css so I'm a little bit at a loss... I want to keep the dark background, but I want to create a small border with a slightly different color around my postings. If my guess is correct, then I should modify some of these definitions:

```
body {
  background:$bgcolor;
  margin:0;
  color:$textcolor;
  font: x-small "Trebuchet MS", Trebuchet, Verdana, Sans-serif;
  font-size/* */:/**/small;
  font-size: /**/small;
  text-align: center;
  }
a:link {
  color:$linkcolor;
  text-decoration:none;
  }
a:visited {
  color:$visitedlinkcolor;
  text-decoration:none;
  }
a:hover {
  color:$titlecolor;
  text-decoration:underline;
}
a img {
  border-width:0;
  }
```

Here is a pastie with the entire template I'm using: http://pastie.org/932535

Is there a quick way to achieve the desired effect? Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add border around each individual post you can try adding this to the class `.post`:

```
.post {
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Got it now... border:10px dotted $bordercolor;

Answer (score 0):

The following can change some of the post properties. I use it to make the corners round.

```
div.post{
  border:2px solid gold;
  border-radius:10px;
}
```